# Xcode: Jump back within file?

Tags: keyboard, xcode, shortcut

Let's assume:

- I'm looking at function `foo`. Inside `foo`, a function `bar` is called.
- I follow `bar` to the definition (in the same file) to see what it does.
- Now I want to go back to `foo`

Is there a shortcut for this? I know about "Go Back" and "Go Forward", but they only work when `bar` is defined in another file, and not for going back and forward within the same file...

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using? Becasue I can jump back and forth inside the same file using "Go Back"/"Go Forward". I have v. 9.2

Comment: Oh, really strange, actually it sees to work now... *scratchinghead*. I'm sure when I tested this last it didn't. Maybe a recent update? Also on 9.2 now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it works like this in the current Xcode version 9.2.

I can jump back and forth inside the same file using "Go Back"/"Go Forward".